# Login to facebook by native fb app

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, authentication, facebook-login

I have created app with logging in to facebook, but it is only through web. I know that in android it is also possibility to log in through native facebook app which is installed on phone, but I didn't find the way to do the same in Windows Phone 8. Is there any option to do this?

Comment: You are searching for app like this or you want to create native app. If it is searching for something like that google it you will see that Facebook will not build app like this for windows.http://venturebeat.com/2012/10/30/facebook-says-it-isnt-building-a-windows-8-app-directs-us-to-microsoft/. If you want to create a native app just check how to create one. Anyway this question is too broad for SO in my opinion !

Comment: @mybirthname I am already have created app with login through facebook web, but I want also login through (if user have installed facebook app on his device) native fb app. It is not too broad question. Windows phone support this way or not?

Comment: This is not supported in Windows Phone 8